# adding a custom icon to a tinyMCE button

Tags: javascript, angularjs, plugins, tinymce

I'm trying to add a Font-Awsome icon to a button I added to tinyMCE thus:

```
 ed.addButton('youtube', {
     title: 'Add Video' ,
     icon: 'icon-youtube',
     onclick: function () {
     //do stuff here...
 }
```

using an image like the docs suggest was not acceptable but for some reason I am not able to make this work. any ideas?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

this CSS based solution seems to work nicely:

```
 i.mce-i-[FONT-AWESOME-CLASSNAME]:before {   // FONT-AWESOME-CLASSNAME e.g. "icon-youtube"
    content: "[FONT-AWESOME-CONTENT]";       // FONT-AWESOME-CONTENT e.g. "\f166"
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    text-decoration: inherit;
    color: #000;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    padding-right: 0.5em;
    position: absolute;
    top: 15%;
    left: 0;
 }
```

it is based on [matt-royal](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/51860/matt-royal)'s answer on [this stack exchange wordpress thread](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/152355/130463)

Comment: @msqar, just go to http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/icons/ and do "inspect element" on an Icon, then look for the ":before" element in the html and check that element's styling.

Comment: Note that you need to put double quotes around the [FONT-AWESOME-CONTENT]. I've edited the answer to include them.

Comment: As of TinyMCE 4.3 its no longer font awesome. I think it's icomoon now.

Answer (score 13):

I know this is old, but I thought I would throw in my answer for anyone who is interested. I am using TinyMCE 4. I added this to my CSS

```
.mce-ico.mce-i-fa {
    display: inline-block;
    font: normal normal normal 14px/1 FontAwesome;
    font-size: inherit;
    text-rendering: auto;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}
```

then when I am setting the icon for the buttons I just use.

```
editor.addButton('adjust', {
    tooltip: 'Adjust Layout',
    icon: 'fa fa-adjust',
    onclick: function () {
        dialogLayout(editor, url, settings);
    }
});
```

basically this will let you use any font awesome icons without having to have a specific class layout for each icon.

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 10):

From what I understand you trying to add a button with an image in the list of icons tinyMCE.

```
 tinymce.PluginManager.add("youtube", function (editor) {   
    editor.addButton('youtube', {
        tooltip: 'Add video',
        image: tinymce.baseURL + '/plugins/youtube/icons/youtube.gif',
        onclick: function() {

        }
    }); 
});
```

Create a folder (I named "youtube") in this folder create another folder (I named "icons" in which you put your image), then create your file youtube.js under youtube folder.

Comment: thank you for your time. as I mentioned above I was trying to use a custom font-face **icon** as opposed to using an **image** file directly. the solution above did it.

Answer (score 4):

In [TinyMCE v5](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/), there's a new [`tinymce.editor.ui.Registry`](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/api/tinymce.editor.ui/tinymce.editor.ui.registry) method called [**addIcon**](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/api/tinymce.editor.ui/tinymce.editor.ui.registry/#addicon), that registers a new SVG icon, quoting:

> Registers a new SVG icon, the icon name reference can be configured by any TinyMCE 5 Ui components that can display an icon. The icon is only available to the editor instance it was configured for.

---

**Method Parameters:**

```
addIcon(name: String, svgData: String)
```

- **name** (String) - Unique name identifying the new icon.
- **svgData** (String) - The SVG data string the browser will use to render
  the SVG icon.

---

**Method Implementation:**

```
// To add a simple triangle icon:
editor.ui.registry.addIcon('triangleUp', '<svg height="24" width="24"><path d="M12 0 L24 24 L0 24 Z" /></svg>');
```

---

Then, you can use that unique name identifier in your custom buttons, for example:

```
editor.ui.registry.addButton('youtube', {
  text: 'Add Video' ,
  icon: 'triangleUp',
  onAction: () => {
    // do stuff here...
  }
});
```

---

**Final Result:**

[image]

Answer (score 3):

For tinymce 5 you can use this sample:

```
editor.ui.registry.addButton('customButton1', {
    text: '<span class="fa fa-youtube"></span>',
    //icon: '<span class="icon-youtube"></span>',
    onAction: () => alert('Button clicked!')
});
```

Comment: For me works: <i style="font-family:FontAwesome" class="fa fa-users"></i>

Answer (score 1):

This simple stylesheet worked for me:

```css
i.mce-i-[FONT-AWESOME-CLASSNAME]:before {   // FONT-AWESOME-CLASSNAME e.g. "icon-youtube"
    content: [FONT-AWESOME-CONTENT];         // FONT-AWESOME-CONTENT e.g. "\f166"
    font-family: FontAwesome;
}
```

It can be used for a toolbar button or menu item equally well.

```
ed.addButton('youtube', {
     title: 'Add Video' ,
     icon: '[FONT-AWESOME-CLASSNAME]',
     onclick: function () { /* magic */ }
}

ed.addMenuItem('youtube', {
     text: 'Add Video' ,
     icon: '[FONT-AWESOME-CLASSNAME]',
     onclick: function () { /* magic */ },
     context: 'view'
}
```

Do not use `position: absolute` because layout in menu will be spoiled.

Answer (score 1):

The following CSS works for TinyMCE 4 and FontAwesome 5:

```
.mce-ico.mce-i-fas {
    display: inline-block;
    font-family: 'Font Awesome 5 Free';
    font-weight: 900;
    text-rendering: auto;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale; }
```